# How can i calculate r square in pandas dataframe elegantly?

Tags: python, pandas

assume i have a dataframe, i want to calculate the r square between two columns.

ps. not the r2(df[0], df[1]), what i want is r2 that use df[0] to ols fit df[1]'s r2.

for example:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2))

In [22]: df
Out[22]: 
          0         1
0  0.776080  0.966668
1  0.922351  0.024381
2  0.859104  0.397823
3  0.607491  0.425335
4  0.732265  0.667846
5  0.336950  0.544515
6  0.236403  0.610943
7  0.811736  0.306425
8  0.110440  0.059754
9  0.469844  0.957298
```

how can i calculate the r2 for column 1 corresponding to column 0?

Comment: `sklearn.metrics.r2_score(df[0], df[1])` shoud do the job

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, sklearn has a method to calculate the r squared.

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

r2_score(df[0], df[1])

# -1.8462387938183031
```

But to answer your question and to calculate it ourselves in pandas, we can use vectorized methods:

```py
res = df[0].sub(df[1]).pow(2).sum()
tot = df[0].sub(df[0].mean()).pow(2).sum()

r2 = 1 - res/tot

# -1.8462387938183031
```

Comment: great, thank Erfan, i think the pandas method is faster?

Comment: Not 100% sure, you can test it with larger datasets, should not be too much difference since scikit-learn uses numpy under the hood.

Comment: Hi, sorry to intrude. I am a mod on Ask Ubuntu. If you would like to undelete [your question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308242/malformed-entry-11-in-file-list-file-etc-apt-sources-list-uri-parse) I will be happy to edit & reopen it. Although the user who commented was right that in general the solution for all such errors is to remove or correct the offending line, there seems to be significant value in explaining *how* to correct it in this particular case. It's your choice of course :)

Answer (score -2):

```
r = df[0].corr(df[1])
r2 = r ** 2
```

Comment: Didn't downvote but this is incorrect. `pandas` `series.corr()` returns Pearson correlation which even squared is not the same as the coefficient of determination R2. See [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/r%C2%B2-or-r%C2%B2-when-to-use-what-4968eee68ed3) for how they differ.